# Putting default text into a new Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

Is there a way to open a new Jupyter notebook from a template? (which would not itself be modified)

I would expect something like this perhaps:

`jupyter --template <template-filename>`

(re-using the existing jupyter-notebook server session if there is one already)

But I don't seem to see how to do it (as of Jupyter 4.0.6)

Answer (score 0):

I admit it's a rather hacky workaround, but just in case there is no implemented solution: You could make an alias in your `.bashrc` like this:

```
alias newnb='cp -i ~/templates/jupyter.ipynb new_notebook.ipynb && juypter notebook'
```

Then, the command `newnb` in your terminal copies the template file to your current directory and invokes the jupyter notebook session on this directory, where you could open `new_notebook.ipynb` with the given content.